# Load external HTML in multiple divs

Tags: jquery, html

I've looked at a few pages addressing multiple divs to load files but they use php.  Is it possible to load from the NAV section external html pages into a multiple divs on the same page using jquery?  I have seen and worked out where I can load one div but not seen how to load into multiple div on same page.   Is this possible?

I am converting from a frame based system that uses 8 windows
- 3 windows for viewing docs that are opened  via 
- 1 main-menu that opens the sub-topic-menu
- 1 subtopic menu that opens into the index windows.
- 3 index windows that sends the files into the viewing windows

Heres the flexbox page

```css
.row1 {
     display: -webkit-flex;
     display: -moz-flex;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     display: -ms-flex;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
     justify-content: flex-start;
     align-items: flex-start;
     flex-wrap: nowrap;
     min-height: calc(70vh); /* set min container height to viewport height */
}

.row2 {
     display: -webkit-flex;
     display: -moz-flex;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     display: -ms-flex;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
     justify-content: flex-start;
     align-items: flex-start;
     flex-wrap: nowrap;
     min-height: calc(30vh); 
     /* set min container height to viewport height */
}


.col-1 {
    flex: 0 1 28%;
    background: beige;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow: scroll;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-height: calc(70vh); /* set min container height to viewport height */
}

.col-2 {
     display: flex;
     flex: 0 1 16%;
     margin-left: auto;
     background: ;
     border: 1px solid black;
     padding: 4px;  
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
     max-height: 70%;
     overflow: hidden;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     min-height: calc(70vh); /* set min container height to viewport height */   
}

.col-3 {
    flex: 0 1 28%;
    background: beige;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow: scroll;
    box-sizing: border-box;
     min-height: calc(30vh); /* set min container height to viewport height */
}


.col-5 {
    flex: 0 1 16%;  
    margin-left: auto;
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-height: calc(30vh); /* set min container height to viewport height */
    min-width: calc(10vw);
}

body {width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0}

li.en24-N {  
    color: black;
 font-family: arial, Sans-serif;
 font-size: 24pt;
}

p {
    color: black;
 font-family: arial, Sans-serif;
 font-size: 12pt;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" >
     <title>frame_scren_lang</title>
    
     <!--Make sure your page contains a valid doctype at the very top-->

     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="row1">
      <div class="col-1" id="file-A">view file A</div>
      <div class="col-1" id="file-B">view file B</div>
      <div class="col-1" id="file-C">view file c</div>
      <div class="col-2" id="subtopic-menu">sub-topic-menu</div>
    </section>

    <section class="row2">
      <div class="col-3" id="index-A"> index to view A files</div>
      <div class="col-3" id="index-B"> index to view B files</div>
      <div class="col-3" id="index-C"> index to view C files</div>
      <div class="col-5" id="main-menutoc">main-menu</div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Couldn't you just open the files with iframes? You wouldn't even need jquery, just javascript.

Comment: Lorddirt.  Thanks for suggestion.  Are not iframes on the way out or have I misunderstood this?   how would iframes  load these pages into my set up?  can you use target when the div is used if I put a iframe inside it?

Answer (score 1):

If the files you are loading are from the same domain as the current page this is pretty simple. You can use the `get` function in Jquery to get the contents as a string and add them as `innerHTML` to the div.

```
<script>
function fillElementFromFile( element, file ) {
    $.get( file ).success( function( data ) {
        // Once the file is fetched the element is filled with it:
        element.innerHTML = data;
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    // array of the files to fetch
    var files = [ "url-1", "url-2", "url-3" ];
    // array corresponding to the one above, of the divs to fill
    var elementIds = [ "#file-A", "#file-B", "#file-C" ];

    $.each( files, function ( index, file ) {
        // Iterates through each file and element
        // Calls the function above to fill each div with its file
        fillElementFromFile( $( elementIds[ index ] ), file );
    });
});
</script>
```

If they aren't from the same domain then you'll get an error caused by your browser's implementation of the Same Origin Policy, a security measure designed to make phishing attacks less likely. Since you don't want to use PHP yourself, you can circumvent the Same Origin Policy with any one of a number of web apps out there that already do this. https://multiverso.me/AllOrigins/ is as good as any, and it's free so I'll use that in this example. You'll replace the `fillElementFromFile( element, file )` function with this:

```
function fillElementFromFile( element, file ) {
    var jsonUrl = 'http://allorigins.me/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent(file) + '&callback=?';
    $.getJSON( jsonUrl, function( data ) {
        element.innerHTML = data.contents;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks jla.  This is actually an offline use note system.  Does this script fill one index location upon a click of a link in the subtopic menu?  The three index div hold different sub-menus.  One might be a vocab index by chapter, one might be an article index by chapter and the last one might be notes by chapter/reading-guide  by chapter.  The subtopics use a-b-c links to send the file to the index-A Index-B or index-C DIV.  Would it help if I showed the menus?   They are css 3 menus.  There are 7 - 40 index files per subject in a school setting

Comment: @loyalosterhoudt Sure, showing the menus would be very helpful. The Jquery method should still work fine, it's a case of fitting it with your current implementation. If the full code is very long perhaps put it into a CodePen or Jsfiddle and paste the link.